# Having a lot of trouble getting pip installed on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal, pip

I'm trying to work with a data representation service (BigML) that offers a REST-style API to its clients. I have to work with this API using Python 2.7, and in order to get it installed, I need pip. However, I can't seem to get pip installed properly for the life of me, even after testing solutions from this website for the past 3 hours. So here's what I've tried to far...

1.) I followed the instructions on this page: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html. Downloaded the "get-pip.py" file and ran `$ python "desktop/get-pip.py"`. I get this result:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip
    Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/user/.pip/pip.log
```

In case it's useful, here's the error log:

```
desktop/get-pip.py run on Mon Jul  7 12:21:14 2014
Downloading/unpacking pip
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: [Errno 1] _      ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error:   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:   /simple/ (Caused by <class 'httplib.CannotSendRequest'>: )
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pip
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
URLs to search for versions for pip:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: [Errno 1]   _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify    failed
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/7t/dnjmslbd0jn2s5wbgj1tnsjc0000gn/T/pip_build_user...
No distributions at all found for pip
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File   "/var/folders/7t/dnjmslbd0jn2s5wbgj1tnsjc0000gn/T/tmpU5dERi/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
 File  "/var/folders/7t/dnjmslbd0jn2s5wbgj1tnsjc0000gn/T/tmpU5dERi/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py" , line 278, in run
 requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,   bundle=self.bundle)
 File "/var/folders/7t/dnjmslbd0jn2s5wbgj1tnsjc0000gn/T/tmpU5dERi/pip.zip/pip/req.py",   line 1177, in prepare_files
 url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
 File "/var/folders/7t/dnjmslbd0jn2s5wbgj1tnsjc0000gn/T/tmpU5dERi/pip.zip/pip/index.py",  line 277, in find_requirement
 raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
 DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pip
```

2.) I tried `sudo easy_install pip` and got the following error message:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-30930.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

3.) Then I tried downloading Python 3.4.1 since pip comes with it, figuring I'd just try to see if I could work with it and hope for no incompatibilities, but even then, when I run `pip help` is says that the command is not found.

4.) I've tried messing with proxies, as well as a number of other random terminal commands that I found in other responses to this same question. Nothing seems to be working.

If you can't tell, I'm not very experienced in this terminal/Unix-ish type of environment so I'd really appreciate any insight into this problem. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

do you need proxy when you access the internet? if you need, set your proxy in the terminal.
or maybe you need add a parameter in your command:
`pip install -U pip`, just like the document mentioned,

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue on my Linux box, and very similar to OSX.

All I needed to do was to get the latest python version from your package manager. Version 3.x I was using the default python install of 2.7.3 and this was not working. 2.7.3 is the default on debian and on OSX.

```
aptitude install python3
```

above - on my debian box. For OSX go get the dmg (latest version 3) from python's website.

```
https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/
```

Double click on the installer and follow the instructions for installing Python 3.x on your Mac.

Now, when you open up terminal and type in

```
python --version
```

2.7 still appears. To open the version you just installed, type "python3" and this will open the latest version of Python 3.x.x.

So to get pip installed

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

And it should take care of any "Could not fetch URL" problems. Wherever you are running python and working on python code, you can now use the latest version 3.x instead. Just make sure to first call python3 instead of python.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you're connected to the internet while installing pip because it'll also download and install 'distribute'.

And if you can't get pip running on python 3.4.1, try adding the following to your path

```
C:/python34/scripts
```